# Field 'recordName' is not marked queryable - cloudkit dashboard

Tags: dashboard, cloudkit, ckrecord

In Cloudkit Dashboard, I select Record Type, Edit Indexes, then I select Add Basic Index. I see in the dropdown createTime, createdBy, eTag, modTime, modifiedBy, recordID and the record fields. I do not see recordName in the dropdown( Attached screenshot). Without creating index on recordName, I cannot query the record in cloudKit Dashboard. I get error: Field 'recordName' is not marked queryable How to create index on recordName?
[image: screen shot of crete index]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into this same issue and solved it by adding `___recordID` as a queryable index. When it is added to the list of indexes, the field changes to `recordName`.

To add this as a queryable index, go to the *Schema Section -> Indexes*, and click *Add Basic Index*.

Comment: That worked for me. I am a CloudKit newbie, so I think it's worth pointing out that it is under the Schema Section -> Indexes and select _Add Basic Index_. In the drop down you should see __recordID as pointed out by kschins

Comment: Great comment, @javsolo. I will update my answer with the pertinent information and a screenshot.

Comment: Adding index on private database, enable us to browse the data, during development stage. However, will such operation affected other user production data? Should we undo such operation, before we deploy the production?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a visual of how to do it in the dashboard. Pay attention to the photos with steps 8) and 18).

**FYI** after doing the below I ran into another issue where I got an error

> Field 'createdBy' is not marked queryable

I'm not sure which one is `createdBy` but to fix it I had to follow the same exact steps below except on step 14), I choose `createdUserRecordName` and all the other system generated field names like `__etag` etc and then had to make sure each one was 15 )`queryable`. I had to press 16) `Save Changes` for each one separately.

A- Select 1) `Databases` > 2) click the dropdown arrow 3) select your `iCloud name` from 4) Xcode

[image]

[image]

B- Next select 5) `Records` (press the drop down arrow) > 6) `Schema` > `Record Types` (after Record Types highlights **click anywhere off of the screen**)

[image]

[image]

C- Next under 7) `Record Type` click `Users` or whatever the name of your record type is

[image]

D- On the next screen you will will see 8) the `recordName` field is set to `None` under `Single Field Indexes`. To change it and fix the issue press 9) Record Types to go back

[image]

E- After you went back a page, on that same page 10) press the down arrow next to `Records` >  then 11) select `Schema` > `Indexes` (after Indexes highlights **click anywhere off of the screen**)

[image]

[image]

F- Next under 12) `Record Type` click `Users` or whatever the name of your record type is

[image]

G- On this page, at the bottom, 13) click `Add Basic Index` and then select 14) recordName

[image]

[image]

H- On that same page, make sure that 15) the `Index Type` is `Queryable`. Then press 16) `Save Changes`. After it saves, press 17) Indexes to go back

[image]

Follow steps 5) to 8) again, but this time 18) the `recordName` field will be set to `**Queryable**` under `Single Field Indexes`

[image]

Comment: But why? Is it mandatory?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do I really need to add a recordName as queryable for production?

Comment: That seems like a different question. This describes the process on how to make field queryable. You should ask that as its own question.

Comment: Apple in their glorious path to screw developers. Why in the name of hell is this not automatic on their server?